# webPackage issue

Tags: web3-providers

i am using angular 7 and web3 version 1.0.0-beta.37 for develop a blockChain application.After run this program i have an issue in terminal . 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/sreejith/Documents/ethereum/angular-dapp/vechain/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'.
please help me to solve this issue already tried to solve this issue through this given below link.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1548

but it's not working.

Comment: seems like you have't install npm library. do a `npm install`

Comment: but i installed the npm packages in project @AchalaDissanayake. it's not working

Comment: check if `eth-lib` is there in `node_modules` and if not install it manually

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake eth-lib is already installed in node modules.

Comment: No idea, nut I think stackoverflow will be a better place to ask this than here